# Can I install puppet to all my clients(hosts) at once?

Tags: unix, manifest, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have installed puppet in the master and one of the clients. Now I want to install it in all the 100 servers I have and sign the certificate. I know I can sign the certificates to all at once, but is there a way to install puppet in all the hosts at once?

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

#### bake the image

Bake the image with puppet agent installed for these 100 servers.

For example, add shell command `yum install -y puppet facter hiera` when bake the centos image

refer:

[packer.io](http://packer.io)

[packer-template](https://github.com/shiguredo/packer-templates)

So if you prepared the image, export to vsphere or generate aws ami image, any instance start with this image will have puppet installed already.

#### Using automation tools

If these clients are already created and running. Use [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) or any other automation tool to install puppet directly

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create image, you can launch bash "**post-script**" that will be executed just after the start of each instances. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts

Example of **AWS CLI** call to launch one instance :

```
ec2-run-instances --key KEYPAIR --user-data-file install.sh <ami_version>
```

and with this in the **install.sh** file :

```
yum install -y puppet facter hiera
```